# React Apex chart show difference in percentage with arrow between bars

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using React Apex grouped bar chart and I have a requirement to show arrow up if value is increasing and down if value is decreasing between two bars. Below is the screen shot which I need to implement.

[image]

I have tried with data labels to show image and other options also but no luck

```
 dataLabels: {
            enabled: props.showHideDataLabel,
            formatter: function (val) {
                let toolTipText = '<img class="downArrow"/>' + 'reduced from baseline scenario';
                const percentage = val !== 0 && val <= 0.01 ? '<0.01' : val.toLocaleString('en');
                return '<div class="row col-12">' + percentage + '%' + toolTipText + '</div>';
           
        },
```